# fit model using all columns as DV individually

Tags: r

Is there a simple way to use each column of a dataframe (one at a time) in a multi-level model? I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29477/how-to-write-a-linear-model-formula-with-100-variables-in-r) post, but it supplies a DV, using other columns as IV's. I am trying to do the opposite- have an unknown DV and a known IV (1)in order to test column means:

```
library(nlme)
exampledf<- data.frame(matrix(ceiling(runif(16,0,50)), ncol=4))
colnames(exampledf)<-c("a","b","id_num","d")
my.control<-list(opt='optim',method='ML')

lme(.~1,random=~1|id_num,na.action=na.fail,data=exampledf,control=my.control) #fails
```

my goal output (the values of these without specifying specific column names):

```
lme(a~1,random=~1|id_num,na.action=na.fail,data=exampledf,control=my.control)
lme(b~1,random=~1|id_num,na.action=na.fail,data=exampledf,control=my.control)
lme(d~1,random=~1|id_num,na.action=na.fail,data=exampledf,control=my.control)
```

Comment: A not-unusual move is to `lapply` across `names(exampledf)`, `paste` them into a formula string, and coerce it to an actual formula, so you end up with a list of models. All together, `lapply(names(exampledf)[-3], function(x){lme(as.formula(paste(x, '~ 1')), random = ~ 1 | id_num, na.action = na.fail, data = exampledf, control = my.control)})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
abc <- function(i){
  form <- as.formula(paste0(colnames(exampledf)[i], "~1"))
  lme(form,random=~1|id_num,na.action=na.fail,data=exampledf,control=my.control)
}

lapply(seq_along(colnames(exampledf)), abc)
```

Comment: How would I also pass a dataframe for the function `abc` to act on?

Comment: @Rilcon42 the dataframe is the same right! so i didn't get your question

Comment: Sorry to clarify I meant: if I wanted to use a different dataframe in the function could I just do something like: `abc(new_df,i)`

Comment: so if you want to use a different data.frame, just specify it in the "data = ". No need to pass it to abc() . abc() already has scope of calling environment's objects